# How to deploy application to a different cluster within same google cloud project?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have one google cloud project, but have 2 different kubernetes clusters. Each of these clusters have one node each.

I would like to deploy an application to a specific kubernetes cluster. The deployment defaults to the other cluster. How can I specify which kubernetes cluster to deploy my app to?

Answer (score 2):

See the cluster with which kubectl is currently communicating:

```
kubectl config current-context
```

Set the cluster with which you want kubectl to communicate:

```
kubectl config use-context my-cluster-name
```

See official docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/) for more details